# Bitmap from Image file is always empty string

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-11

After trying out below ways to convert image into Bitmap in past 3 days, I started doubting that my code is not the issue. It's something else and moved on to try the Sample code provided by Google itself.

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream
BitmapFactory.decodeFile
BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor

ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(getContentResolver(), uri);
bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source);
```

> https://github.com/android/storage-samples/tree/main/ActionOpenDocument
> https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files

I downloaded this sample on ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT ,configured, changed from PDF type to images type files to test in my mobile Android 11 and I faced same issue. So, I think there is something new which I have missed to find over Internet.

Scenario, Use clicks on a button to browse the image. Event will programmatically start Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

```
Intent fileBrowserIntent = null;
fileBrowserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
fileBrowserIntent.setType("image/*");
fileBrowserIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
startActivityForResult(fileBrowserIntent, ActivityResultCode.IMAGE_TO_CONFIGURE);
```

After the file has been selected, In onActivityResult the URI of file is processed by below code and **line 138** is always empty. I have tried overloaded methods by passing BitmapFactory.Options also.

[image]

** To confirm that the issue is not related to the [Storage updates in Android 11](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) I dumped the selected image into a scoped location and then pulled it on to my laptop using Device File Explorer. The images saved are proper so there is no access related concern as far I tested.

**Any thoughts?**

Full code:

const val DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_TAG = "com.example.android.actionopendocument.tags.DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT"

```
/**
 * Simple activity to host [ActionOpenDocumentFragment].
 */
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var noDocumentView: ViewGroup

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_real)

        noDocumentView = findViewById(R.id.no_document_view)
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.open_file).setOnClickListener {
            openDocumentPicker()
        }

        getSharedPreferences(TAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).let { sharedPreferences ->
            if (sharedPreferences.contains(LAST_OPENED_URI_KEY)) {
                val documentUri =
                    sharedPreferences.getString(LAST_OPENED_URI_KEY, null)?.toUri()
                        ?: return@let
                openDocument(documentUri)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_info -> {
                AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage(R.string.intro_message)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                    .show()
                return true
            }
            R.id.action_open -> {
                openDocumentPicker()
                return true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, resultData: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData)

        if (requestCode == OPEN_DOCUMENT_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            resultData?.data?.also { documentUri ->

                /**
                 * Upon getting a document uri returned, we can use
                 * [ContentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission] in order to persist the
                 * permission across restarts.
                 *
                 * This may not be necessary for your app. If the permission is not
                 * persisted, access to the uri is granted until the receiving Activity is
                 * finished. You can extend the lifetime of the permission grant by passing
                 * it along to another Android component. This is done by including the uri
                 * in the data field or the ClipData object of the Intent used to launch that
                 * component. Additionally, you need to add FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                 * and/or FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION to the Intent.
                 *
                 * This app takes the persistable URI permission grant to demonstrate how, and
                 * to allow us to reopen the last opened document when the app starts.
                 */
                contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
                    documentUri,
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                )
                openDocument(documentUri)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun openDocumentPicker() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
            /**
             * It's possible to limit the types of files by mime-type. Since this
             * app displays pages from a PDF file, we'll specify `application/pdf`
             * in `type`.
             * See [Intent.setType] for more details.
             */
            type = "image/*"

            /**
             * Because we'll want to use [ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor] to read
             * the data of whatever file is picked, we set [Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE]
             * to ensure this will succeed.
             */
            addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        }
        startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_DOCUMENT_REQUEST_CODE)
    }

    private fun openDocument(documentUri: Uri) {
        /**
         * Save the document to [SharedPreferences]. We're able to do this, and use the
         * uri saved indefinitely, because we called [ContentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission]
         * up in [onActivityResult].
         */
        getSharedPreferences(TAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit {
            putString(LAST_OPENED_URI_KEY, documentUri.toString())
        }

        val parcelFileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor? =
            contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(documentUri, "r")
        val fileDescriptor: FileDescriptor? = parcelFileDescriptor?.fileDescriptor
        val image: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor)
        parcelFileDescriptor?.close()


        //val fragment = ActionOpenDocumentFragment.newInstance(documentUri)
        // Document is open, so get rid of the call to action view.
       // noDocumentView.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}

private const val OPEN_DOCUMENT_REQUEST_CODE = 0x33
private const val TAG = "MainActivity"
private const val LAST_OPENED_URI_KEY =
    "com.example.android.actionopendocument.pref.LAST_OPENED_URI_KEY"
```

Comment: Please post all code as text. Remove that image.

Comment: `After trying out below ways to convert image into Bitmap` I think you have no image but let the user select an image file. Please post your onActivityResult code where you try to create the bitmap from obtained uri.

Comment: The github code sample for android is also failing with same situation. https://github.com/android/storage-samples/tree/main/ActionOpenDocument

Comment: The image of code snippet OpenDocument() is called in onActivityResult().  Uri uri = intentData.getData();

Comment: Just post your code. We will not follow links. And remove picture.

Comment: I have copy pasted full code of edited android sample app. However I have retained the image so that the explanation can stay.

Comment: Remove all that code. Then remove the picture and post only the code that is now in the picture.

Comment: "and line 138 is always empty" -- what does "empty" mean? "Bitmap from Image file is always empty string" -- bitmaps are not strings. What does "empty string" mean? You are not doing anything with your `image` variable.

Comment: CommonsWare, that's actually a good point. I verified and the whole issue was just the Android Studio's messing up the inline debug value. Adding more info as answer.

Answer (score 0):

After CommonsWare pointed out, what I tried is,
first I took the bitmap as ByteArrayOutputStream and converted into base64 and confirmed that bitmap was not empty.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
qrImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Then to have one more confirmation, I used a

```
AppCompatImageView.setImageBitmap (Bitmap bm)
```

and verified the image was actually holding proper content when rendered.

This was the inline value which made me question my code. Hope it helps to avoid another developer wasting time. The whole issue was just the Android Studio's messing up the inline debug value.
[image: Android Studio Debug mode inline values]

Comment: Same as Showing in my code not Displaying a bitmap image, I am generating the QRCode, still not Showing the image in ImageView anyone help me.